# Jboss Wildfly not closing connections when not in use

Tags: jboss, datasource, wildfly

I am using jboss server with the following configurations timeout:-

```
<timeout>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
</timeout>
<min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
<prefill>true</prefill>
<use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
<flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
```

Now, as soon as the server reaches the max load(30 connections) the datasource details obtained from jboss's CLI reports Active Count = 30 and Available Count = 30.

However, even after reducing the server request to 1, the active count and the Available Count  report 30 as their values.

**Expected** :- The numbers should decrease and ideally only 1 connection from prefilled pool should be used instead of keeping all the connections awake!!

I am seeing the following logs :-

17:34:12,359 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover] (IdleRemover) Notifying pools, interval: 30000

Please help!

Comment: Are you closing the connection so they'll be returned to the pool?

Comment: yes,,we have checked...All connections are properly getting closed from application side..Have also noticed the following logs :-

17:34:12,359 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover] (IdleRemover) Notifying pools, interval: 30000...


any idea on this?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins connections do get closed when we run the following command:-
 /subsystem=datasources/data-source=OracleDS/:flush-idle-connection-in-pool

Any idea as to how do we close the connections when the number of requests or threads go down?

Comment: Which version of Wildfly are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection pool implementation (ironjacamar) on WildFly 8 is in FIFO aka round robin manner. So having `max-pool-size` number of request within time of `idle-timeout-minutes` is enough to keep the pool from shrinking.

I have to use another `decrementer policy` to tell the connection pool to shrink for a size `n` explicitly for every `idle-timeout-minutes` interval.

Sample setting as below

```
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>false</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
                    <capacity>
                        <decrementer class-name="org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.capacity.SizeDecrementer">
                            <config-property name="Size">
                                1
                            </config-property>
                        </decrementer>
                    </capacity>
                </pool>
```

http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.1/en-US/html/ch05.html#deploying_capacity_policies

Comment: Hi
,
Do we also need to specify the flush strategy as :-

<flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>

?
Thanks

Comment: @Ritesh I haven't set it and it's doing well still